# is there any way to turn off/remove "Short Title of the Article" at the top of the page? I am using Elsevier's CAS LaTeX Single Column Template

Tags: elsarticle

Is there any way to remove the "Short Title of the Article" at the top of the page? I am using Elsevier's CAS LaTeX Single Column Template.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please provide a [minimum working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that), starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`, that generates the issue you wish to fix.

Comment: Follow Mico's instructions.